# Add a EULA to a ClickOnce Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I'm working on a program that will be updated occasionally.
I want to have it be able to update it easily/automatically, preferably over the internet, and have a EULA.
ClickOnce has most of the options I want, with publish to website and easy updates, but I can't figure out how to include a EULA with it.

I've thought about just having the EULA pop up when they run the program the first time, but I don't know if it needs to be shown before installing for some obscure legal reason.

I'll consider other options too, but since a lot of out customers aren't that computer literate, the simpler the better.

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834071/clickonce-ask-for-a-license-agreement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this answer.  I have not tried it myself but appears to be what you're interested in:

[Clickonce ask for a License agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834071/clickonce-ask-for-a-license-agreement)